# The process cannot acess the file as it is used by other process when trying to delete files from a directory

Tags: c#

Hi I am trying to delete files from a directory.It is able to delete the first file ,but after that
it is not able to delete other files.It is showing error message "the process cannot access the file as it used by other process.
My code for deleting is

```
             foreach(FileInfo file in files)
             {
            file.delete()
              }
```

Please help

Comment: What's the question here? The file is used by another process, there is not much you can do aside from closing the process...

Comment: Hi Guys ,Is there anyway i am anyway i can remove the file from the process which is accesing it.One more thing i have two files in directory ,it is able to delete the first file ,but while deleting the second file it is showing the issue

Answer (score 4):

The operating system will not let you delete a file in use by another process.

Use this tool to find out what process is accessing the files you are trying to delete:

[Process Explorer v15.3](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Harvey ,but is there anyway by which i can remove the file from the process which is blocking it from deleting